# Directive two way binding watch property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ui-select

I'm trying to use directives in my angularjs app, it's the first i'm trying to apply, so i'm not sure if its right.

The thing is that i want to wrap the ui-select directive into another directive and then i want to watch the selec if a new value has been selected. I'm able to populate the select but i don't know why it doesn't trigger the watch... here is the controller:

```
.controller('IngredientesDatosGeneralesController' ,['$scope', 'PrivateAlergenosUtilsService', 
                                                     'PrivateRestauranteService', 'PrivateIngredienteService',
                                                     function($scope, PrivateAlergenosUtilsService, PrivateRestauranteService,
                                                             PrivateIngredienteService){

    var _this = this;
    _this.PrivateIngredienteService = PrivateIngredienteService;

    _this.proveedorSeleccionado = null;

    _this.proveedores = [];

    PrivateRestauranteService.getProveedores().then(

            function(proveedores){

                _this.proveedores = proveedores;
            },

            function(error){
                _this.proveedores = [];
            }
    );

    $scope.$watch('cntrl.proveedorSeleccionado', function(newValue,oldValue){
          if (newValue && newValue!=oldValue){
              _this.PrivateIngredienteService.getIngregienteDTO().id = _this.proveedorSeleccionado.id;
          }
    }, true);
}]);
```

The following is the directive:

```
.directive('comboDirective', [
                                       function(){
    return {

        restrict : 'E',
        templateUrl: 'resources/js/private/views/utils/combo/combo.html',
        scope : {
            seleccionado : '=',
            elementos : '=',
            descripcion : '@'
        }
    }}]);
```

The combo.html:

```
    <div class="col-xs">
    <label translate>{{descripcion}}</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs">
    <div class="selectStyle">
        <ui-select ng-model="seleccionado" theme="bootstrap" register-custom-form-control disable-validation-message="" required>
            <ui-select-match placeholder="{{'input.seleccionar' | translate}}">{{$select.selected.descripcion}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="elemento in elementos | filter: $select.search">
              <div ng-bind-html="elemento.descripcion | highlight: $select.search"></div>
            </ui-select-choices>
           </ui-select>
           <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally this is how i call the directive:

```
<div ng-controller="IngredientesDatosGeneralesController as cntrl">
    <combo-directive 
        seleccionado="cntrl.proveedorSeleccionado" 
        descripcion="formulario.proveedor"
        elementos="cntrl.proveedores">
    </combo-directive>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include the full controller and template?

Comment: thanks for your interest @mikwat!! i just edited the text, the thing is that the watch method in the controller never triggers when i change the value of the select

Comment: To help debug, can you add a `link` function and a watch inside your directive? Let's verify that `ui-select` is actually updating the model first.

Comment: sorry the delay @mikwat, i wasn't at home for few days. You were right, i put a link method with a watch watching the "seleccionado" variable of the directive and is not being triggered when i change the value of the select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was happening... i don't know why but if i put this config in the directive and using the 'cntrl.' prefix before the "seleccionado" and "elementos" values in the HTML, it works properly.

```
'use strict';

angular.module("private.directives")

    .directive('comboDirective', [
                                           function(){

        return {

            restrict : 'E',
            templateUrl: 'resources/js/private/views/utils/combo/combo.html',
            scope : {
                seleccionado : '=',
                elementos : '=',
                descripcion : '@'
            },
            controller : ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            }],
            controllerAs : 'cntrl',
            bindToController: true
        }
}]);
```